# JavaScript Timer Class: method coming as undefined in browser web consoles

Tags: javascript, class, oop, methods, undefined

I'm currently learning and practicing JavaScript. The other day I stumbled upon some code to create a timer. I decided as a practice exercise it might be fun to try and create a 'class' out of it and attempt to create multiple timer objects that could run concurrently. I have all of this code saved in a .js file which I source from the main html page. The code is as follows:

```
function Timer(length, id, s_name)
{
    this.mins = 0; //set to zero as input is only available in seconds at the moment
    this.field = id;
    this.secs  = length;
    this.name  = s_name;

}
```

The above is my class declaration. It takes 3 arguments which I pass at the creation of the object.

```
  Timer.prototype.init = function()
    {
        //alert(this.field + this.secs + this.name); //test to see if values were initalized properly
        this.timer = setInterval("update()", 1000);
    }
```

The above is my function to initialize the timer. I use setInterval() to call the main function every second.

```
Timer.prototype.update = function()
{

    this.timeField = document.getElementById(this.field);
        if (this.secs == 0)
    {
        if (this.mins == 0)
        {
            this.timeField.innerHTML = (this.name + ' is complete!');
            clearInterval(this.timer);
            alert(this.name + ' is complete!');
            return;
        }
        this.mins--;
        this.secs=59;       
    }
    else
        {
            this.secs--;

        }
    if(this.secs<10)
    {

        this.timeField.innerHTML = "Time left: " + this.mins + ":0" + this.secs + " before " + this.name + " is complete.";

    }
    else
    {
        this.timeField.innerHTML = "Time left: " + this.mins + ":" + this.secs + " before " + this.name + " is complete.";  
    }
}
```

Above is the main function that counts down and updates the appropriate id in the html with 
the appropriate information.

When running and creating a timer I simply use the something such as the following:

```
temp = new Timer(30,'made_up_id','made_up_name');
temp.init();
```

**The Issue**
Before attempting to build this as a class everything worked fine and as intended. I could generate multiple timers across a page - the only downside being only one could run at a time. After trying to build this as 'class' it no longer works. The only hit that I've received after working on this for hours is from the Firefox and Chrome web consoles which like to the line:

```
this.timer = setInterval('update()', 1000);
```

and states that **update is undefined**.

Anyways after much research I haven't the foggiest clue as to why this is occurring. I know from my research that you can't technically create classes in javascript and that there can be quite a few inheritance issues however I don't believe it affects my small project here.

If I can ask additionally to any incite into why I'm getting the error I'm getting, if I'm going about creating this timer object in the/an appropriate way.

Many thanks yous in advance.

Comment: There's just a bit too much you still need to learn before you're ready for something like this. My recommendation would be to work your way through [Codecademy](http://www.codecademy.com/), and then come back to this when you're done. The tutorials on that site should make this a lot easier.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to read and for your suggestion. I couldn't agree more with the having tons more to learn! I'm already working on that but I must admit I often like trying to tackle more complex projects even if it's more than I can chew. I find I learn very well that way. I've already learned a ton about scope from this experiment and can't wait to learn more. Cheers.

Comment: **Never ever pass a string to `setInterval`!** It will be `eval`ed in the global scope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
this.timer = setInterval('update()', 1000);
```

When you use `setInterval` like this, the context of the update function is the `window` object, not the current `this` (Timer). That's why it's undefined.

> Before attempting to build this as a class everything worked fine and
>   as intended.

I guess in this case you define the `update` function in global scope (window) and it works.

In your case, fix it like this:

```
var context = this;
this.timer = setInterval(function(){
                             context.update();
                         }, 1000);
```

Comment: This did the trick. Thank you very much for taking the time to examine my problem and explain the solution. Was very helpful and provides a great starting point to continue learning!